# How I can load a css file in all dashboard pages and my wp theme?

Tags: css, wordpress

How I can load a css file in all dashboard pages and my WP theme with wp_enqueue_style?
My CMS is WordPress.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this into you functions.php, also make sure to create the .css file in the correct spot. here is the [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to the codex

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```